# how to get raw string response in android using volley login?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to receive raw string response using `volley`, but I'm not able to get any type of response. Below is my code that I have tried while hiring the user.

I'm able to get key value pair response, but if we are using raw string, it's not throwing any response in log cat.

```
    username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button Hit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.trim().equals("Message:Valid User")) {
                        Toast.makeText(PostLogin.this, "Resposne"+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("Response:",""+response.toString());
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PostLogin.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostLogin.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
            map.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
            map.put("Content-Type","application/json");
            return map;
        }
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
            String str = "{\"login\":\""+username+"\",\"password\":\""+password+"\"}";
            return str.getBytes();
        };
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: I hope someone can understand this, I have no clue

Comment: @Mikkel here i want to get raw string response from web service they define response in raw format instead of key:value pair hope its clear for your

Comment: You need to provide information about the format you are getting and what you are trying to do with it. Simply dumping your code and a few words isn't enough to go on

Comment: i tryied lile this on my post man :

Comment: {
"user":"ashish",
"password":"Sonu@2015"
}

Comment: @subhash: Is that your response?

Comment: thanks for helping the problem is solve now